# What is the probability of a power set of the sample space?

Tags: probability

Let $\Omega$ be the sample space for an experiment, and, $F$ is the power set of $\Omega$.

We know that $P(\Omega)=1$.

What would be the probability of $F$?

That is, $P(F) = $?

Answer (score 1):

We can only ask what the probability of a subset $A$ of $\Omega$ is.  We **can't** answer this question because $F$ is the powerset of $\Omega$.  It's not a subset of $\Omega$, so we can't ask what its probability is.  (What I mean by "we can't" is that it doesn't make sense to ask this.)

Comment: If we can combine more than one events, why can't we do so?

Comment: @anonymous When we "combine" more than on event, we do it through a union. So if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\Omega$, their "combination" is $A \cup B$.  This is still a subset of $\Omega$, so we can ask about what its probability is.  But $F$ is not a subset of $\Omega$, so we can't ask what its probability is.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple case where you have $\Omega=\{H,T\}$, then $F=\{\emptyset,\{H\},\{T\},\{H\cup T\}\}$ and $P(F)=0+0.5+0.5+1=2$.

Similarly, for a three element set with each possibility $1\over3$, We will have $P(F)={1\over3}\times3+{2\over3}\times3+1=4$.

Start to see the pattern? Essentially, since $card(F)=2^{card(\Omega)}$ and any element appears in exactly in half of subsets of $F$, if we sum up (or integrate in case of infinite elements), each element will be added $2^{card(\Omega)}\over2$ times.

Hence what we are doing is essentially given $\int_{x\in\Omega}x=1$, we want to find $\int_{x\in\Omega}x({2^{card(\Omega)}\over2})$ which equals $2^{card(\Omega)}\over2$

Comment: So, what about the answer of the user46944?

Comment: It depends on the way you define a probability. For instance, we can say that events "head" and "tail" are not comparable to the event "head or tail" but on the other hand we can also say they are all subset of $F$ and having a probability adding up to 2.

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all.  A probability function is a measure (i.e., a set function) which maps into $[0,1]$, so how can $P(F) = 2$?

Comment: That is what I said in my first comment. If you always treat $\Omega$ as your reference then you can only say that $P(H)+P(H\cup T)=1$, however in $F$, you treat $H$ and $H\cup T$ as individual events and they sum up to $1.5$.